# Compilation error on diamond problem(inheritance)

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

Why does the code below throw the following compilation error on msvc ?

> No default constructor exists for class 'Person'

If I don't create a default constructor in the class `Person`, then should I delete the constructor of `Employee` and `Student` that takes only one argument and call `Employee(name,age,grade)` and `Student(name,age,cl)` from ctor of `Manager` although the Base class constructor is never going to get called from `Employee` and `Student` class?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define endl '\n'
using std::cout;

class Person {
    std::string mname;
    int mage;
public:
    //Person() = default;
    Person(const std::string& name, int age) :mname{ name }, mage{ age }{}
};
class Employee :virtual public Person {
    int msalary;
public:
    Employee(const std::string& name, int age, int sal) :Person{ name,age }, msalary{ sal }{}
    Employee(int sal): msalary { sal }{}

};
class Student : virtual public Person {
    int mclass;
public:
    Student(const std::string& name, int age, int cls) :Person{ name,age }, mclass{ cls }{}
    Student(int cls) :mclass{ cls } {}

};

class Manager :public Student, Employee {
private:

public:
    Manager(const std::string& name,int age, int salary,int cl) :Person{name,age}, Student{cl}, Employee{salary} {}
};
int main() {

    Manager manager{ "lorem",40,10000 ,10};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because before entering the body of the ctor `Employee::Employee(int)`, the default ctor `Person::Person()` of `Person` will be used but the compiler will not synthesize a default ctor `Person::Person()` as the parameterized ctor `Person::Person(const std::string&, int)` is present.

Comment: `Employee(int)` and `Student(int)` constructors fail to explicitly construct `Person` base class, and it can't be implicitly constructed either as it lacks a default constructor.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the diamond inheritance (you'll get the problem with only `Person` and `Employee : public Person`). It is caused by the fact that `Person` does not have a default ctor.

Comment: Should I make the default constructor even when I don't intent to make objects from `Employee` and `Student` constructor?

Comment: You can also decide which `name` and `age` the `Person` will have if `Employee(int sal)` is used to construct the object with only `sal`. Then pass this name and age to the base ctor.

Comment: I don't get you. Are you talking about creating `Employee` object or `Manager` object.

Comment: And this is the point where you find out OO is not all about inheritance. There is also room for aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause of the problem:**

Both `Employee` and `Student` have constructors that do not call the only available constructor of the base class `Person` (requireing `name` and `age` parameters). Therefore the compiler will attempt to use a default constuctor fo the base class which is not available.

**You can handle it the following way:**

1. Decide what will be the default `name` and `age` for a `Person` derived class like `Employee`, `Student`.
2. Use the defaults to construct the base, e.g.:

```
static inline const std::string DEFAULT_NAME = "<default_name>";
static inline const int DEFAULT_AGE = 20;
Employee(int sal) : Person(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_AGE), msalary{ sal } {}
```

Comment: Should that matter when I am creating object of Manager` class only? And The base class constructor will be called from `Manager's` constructor. And only single argument constructor of `Employee` and `Student` are called from the `Manager` constructor,

Comment: The default values will not matter for the `Manager` since you initialize them explicitly. But it will allow the code to compile. Keep in mind that if in the future you will instansiate an `Employee` or `Student` with the `int` ctor, these values will have effect (as they should).

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the above code throws compilation error

The **problem** is that  before entering the body of the ctor `Employee::Employee(int)`, the default ctor `Person::Person()` of `Person` will be used but the compiler will not synthesize the default ctor `Person::Person()` as the parameterized ctor `Person::Person(const std::string&, int)` is present.

The error can be reproduced by just the following example:

```
class Person {
    std::string mname;
    int mage;
public:
    //Person() = default;
    Person(const std::string& name, int age) :mname{ name }, mage{ age }{}
};
class Employee :virtual public Person {
    int msalary;
public:
    Employee(const std::string& name, int age, int sal) :Person{ name,age }, msalary{ sal }{}
//--------------------v--------------------->here Person::Person() is called implicitly
    Employee(int sal):   msalary { sal }{}

};
```

[Demo error](https://onlinegdb.com/BN1PzcLwzK)